# stopping Scala compilation after a particular phase

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, scalac

I'm testing my plugin by running it in-process like this:

```
  type PluginMessage = StoreReporter#Info
  def runPlugin(fileName: String): List[PluginMessage] = {
    val settings = new Settings 
    settings.outputDirs setSingleOutput (curDir + "/target")
    settings.classpath.tryToSet(List(
      "project/boot/scala-" + scalaVersion + "/lib/scala-compiler.jar" +
      ":project/boot/scala-" + scalaVersion + "/lib/scala-library.jar"))
    val reporter = new StoreReporter
    val compiler = new Global(settings, reporter) {
      override protected def computeInternalPhases() {
        super.computeInternalPhases
        for (phase <- new AlacsPlugin(this).components)
          phasesSet += phase
      }
    }
    (new compiler.Run).compile(List(testPrefix + fileName))
    reporter.infos.toList
  }
```

However, given the slow speed of `scalac` I'd really like for compilation to end after a certain phase (specifically, after my plugin runs). Unfortunately `Global.cancel` doesn't have the intended effect. How might I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

scalac has an argument explicitly for this purpose.  As of 2.9.0.RC2 you can specify at the command line:

```
-Ystop-after:<phasename>
```

And in earlier versions:

```
-Ystop:<phasename>
```

To do the equivalent directly from a `Settings` instance, this is defined as `stopAfter` (or `stop` in earlier versions)

Comment: This is a *really* good answer, but I wonder if there's a way to pull this off in 2.8.0/1 since those are the versions most plugins are targetting at the moment.

Comment: I believe that `-Ystop` was present in 2.8. I wasn't just referring to earlier versions only within 2.9.x